# How do I get records before and after given one?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table structure:

```
Id, Message
1, John Doe
2, Jane Smith
3, Error
4, Jane Smith
```

Is there a way to get the error record and the surrounding records? i.e. find all Errors and the record before and after them.

Comment: First you define before and after. there is no guaranteed order to pick out what is before and after.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
;WITH numberedlogtable AS
(
SELECT Id,Message, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS RN
 FROM logtable
)

SELECT Id,Message
FROM numberedlogtable
WHERE RN IN (SELECT RN+i
             FROM numberedlogtable
             CROSS JOIN (SELECT -1 AS i UNION ALL SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1) n
             WHERE Message='Error')
```

Comment: could you please explain in layman's terms? if not, no worries. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Because we don't know whether or not your id sequence can have gaps I used `ROW_NUMBER()` to get a guaranteed sequence with no gaps. This query is put into a common table expression and used twice. Once to find the row numbers with errors. This is then cross joined onto the small table so for each row number found we get 3 row numbers (previous, target and next). Once the row numbers of interest are determined that gets plugged back into the original query to retrieve the corresponding records.

Comment: @MartinSmith, Can you please help me out for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59299909/get-null-values-before-and-after-records-based-on-given-input

Answer (score 6):

```
WITH    err AS 
        (
        SELECT  TOP 1 *
        FROM    log
        WHERE   message = 'Error'
        ORDER BY
                id
        ),
        p AS
        (
        SELECT  TOP 1 l.*
        FROM    log
        WHERE   id <
                (
                SELECT  id
                FROM    err
                )
        ORDER BY
                id DESC
        )
SELECT  TOP 3 *
FROM    log
WHERE   id >
        (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    p
        )
ORDER BY
        id
```

Comment: +1 - Deals with gaps in ID column very well and should run pretty quick.

Answer (score 3):

Adapt this routine to pick out your target.

```
DECLARE @TargetId  int
SET @TargetId = 3

select *
 from LogTable
 where Id in (--  "before"
              select max(Id)
               from LogTable
               where Id < @TargetId
              --  target
              union all select @TargetId
              --  "after"
              union all select min(Id)
               from LogTable
               where Id > @TargetId)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH Logs AS 
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id), id, message as rownum  FROM LogTable lt
) 
SELECT curr.id, prev.id, next.id 
FROM Logs curr 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Logs prev ON curr.rownum+1=prev.rownum 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN Logs next ON curr.rownum-1=next.rownum 
WHERE curr.message = 'Error'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select id,messag from 
 (Select (Row_Number() over (order by ID)) as RNO, * from #Temp) as A, 
 (select SubRNO-1 as A, 
  SubRNO as B, 
  SubRNO+1 as C 
  from (Select (Row_Number() over (order by ID)) as SubRNO, * from #Temp) as C
  where messag = 'Error') as B
  where A.RNO = B.A or A.RNO = B.B or A.RNO = B.C
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, message from tbl where id in (
    select id from tbl where message = "error"
    union
    select id-1 from tbl where message = "error"
    union
    select id+1 from tbl where message = "error"
    )
```

Comment: What if `id` s are not consecutive?

Comment: it will not work; but in the example given they are consecutive.

Comment: @Nim: you could just as well hardcode `2`, `3`, `4` — in example they are! :)

Comment: hardly, I am assuming its an auto increment as they are common

Comment: @Nim: deleting records from a table is common too.

Comment: having a requirement where the "before and after" refers specifically to the id is also common too.  I think we could go for ages discussing the merits, it aint the greatest bit of code ever written I will admit that. But it might work, and it is very simple.

Comment: @Nim: in this set: `(2, 5, 8)`, `2` is before `5` and `8` is after `5`.

Comment: And ? If that was the question I would have given a different answer. The question gave an example of consecutive numbers, so I answered it.

Comment: -1 - As soon as you have non-consecutive ids your query will fail or return nulls.

Comment: @JNK: it will neither fail nor return `NULLS`: it will just return less records than expected.

Comment: auto increment ids often have gaps as well due to deletes and rollbacks. It is always a bad idea to assume no gaps.

Answer (score 0):

## Get fixed number of rows before & after target

*Using UNION for a simple, high performance query (I found selected answer **WITH** query above to be extremely slow)*

Here is a high performance alternative to the **WITH** top selected answer, when you know an ID or specific identifier for a given record, and you want to select a fixed number of records **BEFORE** and **AFTER** that record. Requires a number field for ID, or something like date that can be sorted ascending / descending.

**Example:** You want to select the 10 records before and after a specific error was recorded, you know the error ID, and can sort by date or ID.

The following query gets (inclusive) the 1 result above, the identified record itself, and the 1 record below. After the UNION, the results are sorted again in descending order.

```sql
SELECT q.*
FROM(
    SELECT TOP 2
        id, content
    FROM
        the_table
    WHERE 
        id >= [ID]
    ORDER BY id ASC
    UNION
    SELECT TOP 1
        id, content
    FROM
        the_table
    WHERE 
        id < [ID]
    ORDER BY id DESC
) q
ORDER BY q.id DESC
```

Answer (score -1):

```sql
WITH ctl AS
(

SELECT Id, Name, CASE WHEN Name = 'Error' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END RowFlag,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS RN
FROM 
  (
    select 1 id, 'John' Name union all 
    select 20,   'Smith'  union all 
    select 30,   'Error'  union all 
    select 40,   'Jane'  union all 
    select 50,   'Wane'  
  ) S
)
SELECT * 
FROM ctl
JOIN (SELECT RN from ctl where RowFlag = 1) AS s ON ctl.RN >= s.RN -1 AND ctl.RN <=s.RN +1;
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has a few answers—including one that has been validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?