# Find next or previous ID when query contains multiple cases

Tags: mysql, sql

I am looking for the most efficient way to find the next or previous ID of the following query:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM transactions 
 ORDER 
    BY CASE order_status 
       WHEN 'order_accepted' THEN 1 
       WHEN 'processing_order' THEN 2 
       WHEN 'order_send_mailer' THEN 3 
       WHEN 'order_send' THEN 4 
       WHEN 'order_received' THEN 5 
       WHEN 'order_refunded' THEN 6 
       ELSE 7 END
      , id DESC limit 1;
```

I tried adding a `where id > '$id'` or `where id < '$id'` claus to the query but it didn't give me te next or previous ID I was looking for.

For those that need some explanation of what I am trying to do: It's to go to the next or previous order by case with a forward of backward button.

What it currently looks like:

```
-id- -order_status-
9399 order_accepted
9398 processing_order
9363 processing_order
9403 order_send_mailer 
9318 order_send
9346 order_received 
9345 order_received 
9050 order_refunded
```

The next ID for example of 9403 would be 9363 and previous ID would be 9318

Comment: Consider handling pagination in application code

Comment: I think we also need an explanation of what you are trying to do.  Can you include sample table data?

Comment: Are those `order_status` values always in that order?

Comment: @Schwern yes it is

Comment: edited my question, hope it's a little bit more clear now

Comment: ('Limit 1' won't return that result set!!)

Comment: @Niels . . . Why not just use a time column or auto-incremented id to get the next and previous values?

Answer (score 0):

Change your `order_status` into an [`enum` column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/enum.html). This will save disk space and make sorting by order_status simpler and faster.

```
-- Add a new version of the column using an enum.
-- These strings are aliases for ordered numbers.
-- 'order_accepted' is 1, 'processing_order' is 2, etc.
alter table transactions add column enum_order_status enum(
    'order_accepted',
    'processing_order',
    'order_send_mailer',
    'order_send',
    'order_received',
    'order_refunded'
  ) not null;

-- Copy the status into the new enum column.
-- MySQL will translate the string into the number for you.
update transactions
set enum_order_status = order_status;

-- Drop the old column.
alter table transactions drop column order_status;

-- Rename the new enum column.
alter table transactions rename column enum_order_status to order_status;

-- Index it.
create index transactions_order_status on transactions(order_status);

-- Enjoy your vastly simplified and much faster query.
select *
from transactions
order by order_status, id desc
```

---

That's not actually necessary, but it makes everything much simpler.

With that out of the way, use the window functions [lead and lag](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lag) to refer to the previous and next rows in a query.

```
select
  id, order_status,
  lead(id) over w, lead(order_status) over w,
  lag(id) over w, lag(order_status) over w
from transactions
window w as (order by order_status, id desc);
```

Note, window functions were added in MySQL 8. If you're using an older version I recommend upgrading ASAP; MySQL 8 has many big improvements. Otherwise [you can simulate it with correlated subqueries and self-joins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37538912/14660).

---

If you want the previous and next rows of a specific row, use [the technique from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3718426/14660). We add [`row_number`s](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number) to the table in the desired order, and then fetch 9403 and its previous and next row by row number.

```
-- Add a row number to your table in the desired order.
with ordered_transactions as (
  select
    *, row_number() over w as rn
  from transactions
  window w as (order by order_status, id desc)
)
select *
from ordered_transactions
-- Find the row number for ID 9403, then add -1, 0, and 1.
-- If 9403 is row number 5 you'll fetch row numbers 4, 5, and 6.
where ot.rn in (
  select rn+i
  from ordered_transactions ot
  -- All this is doing is making us three "rows" where i = -1, 0, and 1.
  cross join (SELECT -1 AS i UNION ALL SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1) cj
  where ot.id = 9403
);
```

[Try it](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dac010fd797d683d5baa28a1d9401e3a).